# Aeson parse IHP payload to record type

Tags: json, haskell, aeson, ihp

### What I am trying to do?

I am receing a JSON payload in IHP and would like to convert to record type.

---

### What I have

Record type that I've generated with the IHP generators

```
data Resource' userId providerId bookings = Resource 
  { id :: (Id' "resources")
  , createdAt :: UTCTime
  , updatedAt :: UTCTime
  , userId :: userId
  , providerId :: providerId
  , name :: Text
  , bookings :: bookings
  , meta :: MetaBag
  } deriving (Eq, Show)
type Resource = Resource' (Id' "users") (Id' "providers")(QueryBuilder.QueryBuilder "bookings")
```

I wasn't able to directly convert the json payload to `Record` and therefore creating another temporary record to fetch values from json.

```
data ResourceCreateRequest = ResourceCreateRequest { name :: String }

instance FromJSON ResourceCreateRequest where
  parseJSON = withObject "Resource" $ \o -> ResourceCreateRequest <$> o .: "name"
```

**JSON payload**

```
{"name": "X"}
```

My idea was to use temp record to replace just few specific fields in IHP's generated `newRecord @Resource`. To show the results I am using (or trying to) in the controller

```
-- JRCR is a qualified name of the module with my temporary record
"application/json" -> renderJson (newRecord @Resource){ name = (JRCR.name getRequest) }
```

---

### Question

Apparently I am having issues on `Value` -> `Resource` or `Value` -> `ResourceCreateRequest` conversion and cannot get it done correctly. Can you please help me out?

### Current error

```
Record update is ambiguous, and requires a type signature
    * In the second argument of `($)', namely
        `(newRecord @Resource) {name = (JRCR.name getRequest)}'
      In the expression:
        renderJson $ (newRecord @Resource) {name = (JRCR.name getRequest)}
      In a case alternative:
          "application/json"
            -> renderJson
                 $ (newRecord @Resource) {name = (JRCR.name getRequest)}
   |
52 |           "application/json" -> renderJson $ (newRecord @Resource){ name = (JRCR.name getRequest) }
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that type inference and `DuplicateRecordFields` don't work well together. Here's a minimal program that demonstrates the same problem you're having, but without involving IHP or any other third-party code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields, TypeApplications #-}

data Foo = Foo { name :: String } deriving Show
data Bar = Bar { name :: String } deriving Show

class Baz a where
    baz :: a

instance Baz Foo where
    baz = Foo ""

instance Baz Bar where
    baz = Bar ""

main :: IO ()
main = print $ (baz @Foo){ name = "qux" }
```

The solution here is to change `baz @Foo` to `baz @Foo :: Foo`. In this case, just `baz :: Foo` would work too.

Similarly, changing `newRecord @Resource` to `newRecord @Resource :: Resource`, or maybe `newRecord :: Resource`, should fix your code.

Comment: Future version of GHC won't support `DuplicateRecordFields`. Any ideas how that would be handled then?

Comment: @hrust I don't know of any plans to remove that extension. Are you talking about the `-Wambiguous-fields` warning? If so, see https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0366-no-ambiguous-field-access.rst